# Should reverse-dns results resolve to the original IP?

Tags: reverse-dns

I'm interested in taking a log file that I will review and "beautifying" its entries by replacing IPs with their reverse-DNS entries.

For instance:

- `75.76.69.69`: meaningless

  - RDNS → `dynamic-75-76-69-69.knology.net.`
    I can see this is a dynamic IP from [WideOpenWest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Open_West), probably residential
- `185.100.85.212`: meaningless

  - RDNS → `vc.gg`
    I can see this is a personal website, probably an industrial or rented IP

It's *instant*, **useful** information… iff it's true.

But an IP owner can just set its RDNS output to whatever it wants. An attacker could easily "blame" some other network or innocent domain if I rely on these without any further verification.

Therefore, I was thinking to only thus display IPs whose RDNS result resolves back to it: the IP claims to represent some DNS name *and* that DNS name claims to be represented by that IP. In that case, I can be certain that I'm unlikely to have any wool pulled over my eyes by viewing the DNS names instead.

However… in the first example given (with the 2 joke octets replaced with my *actual* IP), I do get an `NXDOMAIN` result. So, is this normal? Is there any standard saying what RDNS entries "should" be, represent, resolve to, or contain?

Comment: there isn't really any requirement that a given IP exists in any zone at all, or that if it does, that zone is backed by a reverse lookup zone, and there is also no requirement that the reverse lookup zone for that domain contains an entry for that particular IP.

Comment: @FrankThomas The first fact, I knew; but the second fact is what I'm looking for more detail on: what _is_ the reverse lookup result supposed to be, if anything? Or is it just a free-form field for network admins to put anything they feel appropriate as long as it's a valid DNS name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per section 3.3.1 or [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035), an administrator can supply any value in the name section of a PTR record, provided it meets the standard rules for valid character set and length.

> PTRDNAME        A  which points to some location in the
> domain name space.
>
> PTR records cause no additional section processing.  These RRs are
> used in special domains to point to some other location in the domain
> space. These records are simple data, and don't imply any special
> processing similar to that performed by CNAME, which identifies
> aliases.  See the description of the IN-ADDR.ARPA domain for an
> example.

I'd guess a lot of DNS server front-ends may prevent an admin from entering inappropriate data, but there is no requirement that the software do so.